# How to register a BroadcastReceiver whenever a app is launched?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an app-locking application.

I have used a service which is using a timer of 2 secs to detect whether my locked app is launched or not, its working well and good, but now I want to remove the service and instead of the service I would like to register a receiver which will receive the notification whenever any app is launched, i have got a couple of ideas but I don't know how to implement those

1. is it possible to register any `intent-filter` which will receive whenever a app is launched, each and every app must use

   ```
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   ```

   is there any way to receive a any notification that a app is launched
2. is it possible to receive a notification whenever a app is taking the foreground or top of the app stack list which is visible to the user
3. is it possible to implement a custom listener which will listen for my locked apps to be launched

EDIT: can i keep a listener whenever the user moves from the home page or the launcher page(whenever he launches a app automatically he has to move from the home screen or the launcher screen)

any ideas, or links or direction to which way I should proceed is appreciable

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383431/1554935

Comment: There is [no such broadcast](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fNTysSA8mWQ) but there are [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956904/how-to-detect-app-launching-event-in-android-and-start-broadcast-reciever). I.e. your service method.

Comment: Do you have splash screen? do this inside splashscreen

Comment: @ Ritesh Gune i know how to register a broadcast receiver but my question is different

@zapl i got your point but can you look forward to the other ideas i have mentioned are those possible??

Sameer i didnt't get you properly? i don't have a splashscreen as of now, but even if i have one what am i supposed to do inside it?

Comment: There is nothing I know of that could be used to get notified about app starts.through other means than broadcasts. So 2) and 3) are not working, 1) generates no broadcast.

Comment: @zapl is there any other intent filter, other than launcher which sends a broadcast which i can receive?

Comment: @Ari No. The app intentfilter is not used for broadcasts here. If you do `startActivity(Intent)` you don't send a broadcast. You give that intent directly to the Android system which then checks it's list of registered apps for matching ones. Similar to broadcasts but it's something different. Its just using the same Intent filter mechanism but not the broadcast mechanism.

Comment: @zapl thank you for replying,you are saying

>You give that intent directly to the Android system which then checks it's list of registered apps for matching ones...

 can i somehow handle this feature, is there anything to do with signatures of the apps?

or can we create any custom intent-filter

Comment: @Ari No, there is nothing you can do but what you currently do. Android tries to prevent that apps can interfere with other apps to protect users from malicious apps (e.g. replace banking app with fake app, "pay 100$ or I'll block  all apps.."). There is really no other way than checking `ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses` periodically and I wouldn't be surprised if that will get restricted in the future.